# Xcode Release / Swift Conditional code

Tags: swift, xcode

```
func print(_ object: Any) {
#if DEBUG
    Swift.print(object)
#endif
}
```

I have this function overloading the default print function so that prints only occur on the DEBUG builds, however, on RELEASE builds it just closes the app and I can't determine why.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Reading through the logs and I found that when this code gets called, the Crashlytics catches the following as the reason for the crash:

```
[Crashlytics:Crash] Warning: NSUncaughtExceptionHandler is 'mp_handleUncaughtException' in '/Users/daredevil/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2FB9948E-77D9-4F76-9928-15ED2ED18E4A/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/39AB3114-EB6F-4520-B8FF-90908C5B9654/App.app/Frameworks/Mixpanel.framework/Mixpanel'
```

Whenever I remove the global override print function, this crash doesn't occur.

EDIT 2: Ignore the previous edit.  Mixpanel has nothing to do with the problem. I completely removed it and still got the crash.

Comment: Quite likely a compiler bug, you may want to file a Radar. This should just work.

Comment: `print` doesn't actually send any info to the device log/console, only `NSLog` does.

Comment: @hnh would it be specific to this version of the compiler then? Because I have seen stackoverflow questions recommending this before.  why would it only now cause problems?

Comment: The swift compiler is a mysterious thing ;-) And it is a little hard to analyse this w/o having the code. Can you replicate it in a minimal example? (The essence is still true: this is supposed to work in Swift and is not expected to have unpredictable side effects. I assume that your print function is really a top-level Swift function, not a part of a class.)

Comment: I could not repro on a simple project. It worked as expected. How do you know this is causing your crash? Do you have other conditional code that could be to blame? Are you printing the same object in Debug as Release?

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yeah, printing the same object, and no, no additional condition code.  I also tried to recreate in a simple project and failed.  Basically, with this conditional code commented out, it worked fine without crashing, but with it in it crashes anywhere I have a print function

Comment: Do you have the crash log? What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you figured out what was causing your crash but it might have something to do with the print signature you are using.

I use a similar approach to remove print statements from my release builds, however the print signature I use is:

```
// Only show print statements while in DEBUG
func print(_ item: @autoclosure () -> Any, separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    #if DEBUG
    Swift.print(item(), separator:separator, terminator: terminator)
    #endif
}
```

Comment: So, I never figured it out, and just dropped it all together to be honest.  However, I just went back to a commit I had for that project from when this occurred and swapped signatures and everything works ok.  Not sure if it was this or new XCode version.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend ***not*** doing this. It may have unpredictable secondary effects (as you observed) and it's also completely unnecessary. If you want your print statements to only run on debug, you should define a new function. E.g.

```
func dPrint(_ object: Any) {
   #if DEBUG
       print(object) 
   #endif
}
```

Comment: This still caused a crash

Comment: While I somewhat agree that this may not be recommendable, your rational is wrong. This does NOT have unpredictable side effects. It is a feature of Swift that those are scoped to the module and may explicitly be overridden. This is very likely just one of many bugs in the Swift compiler.